Question body not displayed on SO when viewing a question with the Brave browser
I encounter a weird behavior when viewing Stack Overflow questions where a display: none !important CSS is applied to the question body.
I tried disabling all my extensions one by one, but it seems none of them are causing this behavior.
The behavior was observed in the Brave browser v1.66.115 (2024-05-24, latest build).
Other Stack Exchange sites don't exhibit this behavior. Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge don't exhibit this behavior.


Probably best reported to Brave's bugtracker then.

Doesn't Brave include an ad blocker in their browser?  My guess is that Brave's code is buggy.

@EndAntisemiticHate Oh wow, when I allow trackers and ads, it now shows the question body. Weird that it behaves like this only in SO and not in other stack exchange forums.

Although it's clearly a bug, what you are experiencing actually makes sense from an engineering standpoint.  My guess is that Brave has erroneously written a filter rule that hides the entire question body on SO.  SO uses a different domain than other SE sites, hence the filter would not get applied to other SE sites.  I'm just "shooting from the hip" by guessing at their implementation (I haven't reviewed their code), but it's a common implementation, and it matches what you are experiencing.

Related: Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need? - e.g. (my emphasis), "We support the last two stable versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use.". (Nothing is implied.)

Given that it only happens in Brave browser, and that the issue disappears when you allow trackers and ads in Brave, it is very likely that this is a bug in Brave browser (specifically their ad blocker).
You can report the issue to Brave browser here: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues

I've not used Brave much but I suppose it should also allow for the filter rules to be adjusted by the user.

@VLAZ I would hope so, but I don't use it either.  To help SO, I think it's best for the OP to report the issue to Brave so that the issue can be fixed for all SO community members and visitors.

I have submitted an issue regarding this, https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/38664
